# Converting a date string to a DateTime object using Joda Time library

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a date as a string in the following format `"04/02/2011 20:27:05"`. I am using Joda-Time library and would like to convert it to `DateTime` object. I did:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("04/02/2011 20:27:05")
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
Invalid format: "04/02/2011 14:42:17" is malformed at "/02/2011 14:42:17"
```

How to convert the above date to a `DateTime` object?

Comment: For anyone arriving here looking for how to parse date Strings using the `java.time` package in Java 8, try using [`LocalDateTime.parse`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22463063/2646526) or `Instant.parse`.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Use [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :).That worked with formatter.parseDateTime. As per the API there is no parse method for DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Hi, is it possible that the formatter doesn't accept timezones? "zz" returns "MEZ", when applying the `toString` function, but I cannot parse from it: `Invalid format: "31. Januar 2013 06:38:08 MEZ" is malformed at "MEZ"`. Is this a known issue? How can I avoid it? Regards.

Comment: @Danyel: You can add timezones like this DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")       .withLocale(Locale.ROOT)       .withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());

Comment: I get an Invalid format: "2014-11-04T17:41:52.000+01:00" is malformed at "+01:00" with the following formatter: private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'"); DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseDateTime((String) customSoftware.get(header[3])) on joda-time 2.2

Comment: Still the same after upgrading to joda-time 2.5

Comment: After removing the single quotes around the ZZ it worked. I wonder what these single quotes mean...

Comment: @StephaneEybert (or anyone else) The single quotes mean that something is a literal character to be expected in the string, and is not to be considered part of the pattern. For instance: if your date comes in as "2015-08-dd30" for some reason, you would specify "yyyy-MM-'dd'dd", indicating that the first dd is a literal part expected in the string, and the second dd (outside of the apostrophes) is the actual day that needs to be parsed. So in your earlier case it would have worked if instead of the actual timezone you would have put "ZZ" at the end of your incoming datetime-string.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormat` not found here. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this still valid in Java 8?

Comment: Date date = formatter.parseDateTime(string).toDate();

Answer (score 67):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add that, as of JodaTime 2.0, you can do this with a one-liner:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.parse("04/02/2011 20:27:05", 
                  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: What should I put to the import section?

Answer (score 20):

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("04/02/2011 20:27:05");
```

Comment: Should be: DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("04/02/2011 20:27:05")

Answer (score 18):

From comments I picked an answer like and also adding TimeZone:

```
String dateTime = "2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
        .withLocale(Locale.ROOT)
        .withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());

DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 14):

Your format is not the expected ISO format, you should try

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time = format.parseDateTime("04/02/2011 20:27:05");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), as in `DateTimeFormat`

```
Date startDate = null;
Date endDate = null;
try {
    if (validDateStart!= null) startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(validDateStart + " " + validDateStartTime);
    if (validDateEnd!= null) endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(validDateEnd + " " + validDateEndTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: kirlisakal doesn't in this case, but don't create a shared instance of a SimpleDateFormat as it isn't thread-safe, it is a nightmare to debug if you do

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And the java.time classes are thread-safe, unlike the legacy classes.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "04/02/2011 20:27:05" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplant the venerable *Joda-Time* project.

Parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as your input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
String input = "04/02/2011 20:27:05" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2011-02-04T20:27:05

Tip: Where possible, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values as text rather than format seen here. Conveniently, the java.time classes use the standard formats when parsing/generating strings.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You need a [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) appropriate to the format you're using.  Take a look at the docs for instructions on how to build one.

Off the cuff, I think you need `format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/y H:m:s")`

Answer (score 2):

An simple method :

```
public static DateTime transfStringToDateTime(String dateParam, Session session) throws NotesException {
    DateTime dateRetour;
    dateRetour = session.createDateTime(dateParam);                 

    return dateRetour;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **two ways** this could be **achieved**.

**DateTimeFormat**

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("04/02/2011 20:27:05");
```

**SimpleDateFormat**

```
        String dateValue = "04/02/2011 20:27:05";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); //  04/02/2011 20:27:05

        Date date = sdf.parse(dateValue); // returns date object
        System.out.println(date); // outputs: Fri Feb 04 20:27:05 IST 2011
```

Comment: Both of therm outdated. There is a modern way too; it’s in [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038725/5772882). Also you aren’t contributing anything that isn’t already in several other answers. And when Joda-Time is asked for, suggesting the even longer outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` is *bad* in my most honest opinion.