# How can I parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timestamp, java-time

Java 8 added a new [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API for working with dates and times ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

I have date and time as string (e.g., `"2014-04-08 12:30"`). How can I obtain a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instance from the given string?

After I finished working with the `LocalDateTime` object: How can I then convert the `LocalDateTime` instance back to a string with the same format as shown above?

Comment: FYI, most people most of the time would want a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) rather than a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). The name is counter-intuitive; the `Local` means *any* locality in general rather than a specific time zone. As such, a `LocalDateTime` object is not tied to the time line. To have meaning, to get a specify moment on the time line, you must apply a time zone.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of `LocalDateTime` vs. `ZonedDateTime` vs. `OffsetDateTime` vs. `Instant` vs. `LocalDate` vs. `LocalTime`, how to keep calm about why it's so complicated and how to do it right at the first shot.

Comment: If it wasn't impractically long, `LocalDateTime` would probably have been named `ZonelessOffsetlessDateTime`.

Answer (score 760, accepted):

**Parsing date and time**

To create a `LocalDateTime` object from a string you can use the static [`LocalDateTime.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method. It takes a string and a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) as parameter. The `DateTimeFormatter` is used to specify the date/time pattern.

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

**Formatting date and time**

To create a formatted string out a `LocalDateTime` object you can use the `format()` method.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1986, Month.APRIL, 8, 12, 30);
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "1986-04-08 12:30"
```

Note that there are some commonly used date/time formats predefined as constants in `DateTimeFormatter`. For example: Using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` to format the `LocalDateTime` instance from above would result in the string `"1986-04-08T12:30:00"`.

The `parse()` and `format()` methods are available for all date/time related objects (e.g. `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime`)

Comment: Just to note that DateTimeFormatter is immutable and thread-safe, and thus the recommended approach is to store it in a static constant where possible.

Comment: @micha what if i have "2016-12-31T07:59:00.000Z" this date formate?

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")`

Comment: @Loenix maybe that's because you're trying to call `format()` on the LocalDateTime class instead of on the instance? At least, that's what I did: I confused `DateTime` with `dateTime` in the example above.

Comment: Don't forget the uppercase on MM

Comment: Sadly, it does not extend `Format` or `DateFormat` classes, which makes it somewhat cumbersome to integrate when you're migrating away from regular `Date` usages.

Comment: @Dragas One year after your comment, are there any new classes to help migrate away from regular Date usages?  I have similar code in my project and am looking for a solid conversion before replacing existing code.

Comment: @AJW I bit the bullet and rewrote those bits from `Date` to `LocalDate` and respective classes.

Comment: if you raw time writed in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" you can parse it with standard static formatter:  *DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME* ;

Answer (score 216):

You can also use `LocalDate.parse()` or `LocalDateTime.parse()` on a `String` without providing it with a pattern, if the `String` is in [ISO 8601 format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

For example,

```
String strDate = "2015-08-04";
LocalDate aLD = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
System.out.println("Date: " + aLD);

String strDatewithTime = "2015-08-04T10:11:30";
LocalDateTime aLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(strDatewithTime);
System.out.println("Date with Time: " + aLDT);
```

**Output**,

```
Date: 2015-08-04
Date with Time: 2015-08-04T10:11:30
```

And use `DateTimeFormatter` only if you have to deal with other date patterns.

For instance, in the following example, ***dd MMM uuuu*** represents the day of the month (two digits), three letters of the name of the month (Jan, Feb, Mar,...), and a four-digit year:

```
DateTimeFormatter dTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu");
String anotherDate = "04 Aug 2015";
LocalDate lds = LocalDate.parse(anotherDate, dTF);
System.out.println(anotherDate + " parses to " + lds);
```

**Output**

```
04 Aug 2015 parses to 2015-08-04
```

also remember that the `DateTimeFormatter` object is bidirectional; it can both parse input and format output.

```
String strDate = "2015-08-04";
LocalDate aLD = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
DateTimeFormatter dTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu");
System.out.println(aLD + " formats as " + dTF.format(aLD));
```

**Output**

```
2015-08-04 formats as 04 Aug 2015
```

(See complete [list of Patterns for Formatting and Parsing DateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).)

```
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   G       era                         text              AD; Anno Domini; A
   u       year                        year              2004; 04
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
   D       day-of-year                 number            189
   M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
   d       day-of-month                number            10

   Q/q     quarter-of-year             number/text       3; 03; Q3; 3rd quarter
   Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
   w       week-of-week-based-year     number            27
   W       week-of-month               number            4
   E       day-of-week                 text              Tue; Tuesday; T
   e/c     localized day-of-week       number/text       2; 02; Tue; Tuesday; T
   F       week-of-month               number            3

   a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
   h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
   K       hour-of-am-pm (0-11)        number            0
   k       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-24)  number            0

   H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
   m       minute-of-hour              number            30
   s       second-of-minute            number            55
   S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
   A       milli-of-day                number            1234
   n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
   N       nano-of-day                 number            1234000000

   V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
   z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
   O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;
   X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   x       zone-offset                 offset-x          +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;

   p       pad next                    pad modifier      1

   '       escape for text             delimiter
   ''      single quote                literal           '
   [       optional section start
   ]       optional section end
   #       reserved for future use
   {       reserved for future use
   }       reserved for future use
```

Comment: This answer touched on an important subject: use predefined formatters wherever possible e.g. DON'T create a formatter base on "yyyy-MM-dd", use DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE instead. It'll make your code look a whole lot cleaner. Furthermore, try to maximize the use of ISO8061 format, it'll pay dividends in the long run.

Comment: I want to parse a date for validation like `2018-08-09 12:00:08` but when I parse I see a `T` is added which I don't need. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: @Raghuveer The T is just the ISO-8061 delimiter between date and time. If you have a space in your format instead, you can simply use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` for parsing and formatting. The T will always show in the default (ISO-8061) format, but you can use your own patterns.

Answer (score 53):

Both [Sufiyan Ghori's and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-can-i-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8/28324294#28324294) [micha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-can-i-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8/22463063#22463063) explain very well the question regarding string patterns. However, just in case you are working with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), there isn't any need to apply `DateTimeFormatter` since LocalDateTime is already prepared for it:

**Convert a LocalDateTime to a Time Zone ISO 8601 String**

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC); // You might use a different zone
String iso8601 = zdt.toString();
```

**Convert from ISO8601 String back to a LocalDateTime**

```
String iso8601 = "2016-02-14T18:32:04.150Z";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(iso8601);
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 43):

Parsing a string with date and time into a particular point in time (Java calls it an  "[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)") is quite complicated. Java has been tackling this in several iterations. The latest one, `java.time` and `java.time.chrono`, covers almost all needs (except [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) :) ).

However, that complexity brings a lot of confusion.

The key to understand date parsing is:

### Why does Java have so many ways to parse a date?

1. There are several systems to measure a time. For instance, the historical Japanese calendars were derived from the time ranges of the reign of the respective emperor or dynasty. Then there is, e.g., the [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
   Fortunately, the whole (business) world managed to use the same.
2. Historically, the systems were being switched from/to, for [various reasons](https://www.history.com/news/6-things-you-may-not-know-about-the-gregorian-calendar). E.g., from the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) to the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) in 1582; so, the 'western' dates before that need to be treated differently.
3. And, of course, the change did not happen at once. Because the calendar came from the headquarters of some religion and other parts of Europe believed in other deities, for instance Germany did not switch until the year 1700.

### ...and why is the `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` et al. so complicated

4. There are [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).
   A time zone is basically a "stripe"***[3]** of the Earth's surface whose authorities follow the same rules of when does it have which time offset. This includes summer time rules.

   The time zones change over time for various areas, mostly based on who conquers whom. And one time zone's rules [change over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time) as well.
5. There are time offsets. That is not the same as time zones, because a time zone may be, e.g., "Prague", but that has summer time offset and winter time offset.

   If you get a timestamp with a time zone, the offset may vary, depending on what part of the year it is in. During the leap hour, the timestamp may mean two different times, so without additional information, it can't be reliably converted.

   Note: By *timestamp* I mean "a string that contains a date and/or time, optionally with a time zone and/or time offset."
6. Several time zones may share the same time offset for certain periods. For instance, the GMT/UTC time zone is the same as the "London" time zone when the summer time offset is not in effect.

To make it a bit more complicated (but that's not too important for your use case):

7. The scientists observe Earth's dynamic, which changes over time; based on that, they add seconds at the end of individual years. (So *2040-12-31 24:00:00* may be a valid date-time.) This needs regular updates of the metadata that systems use to have the date conversions right. E.g., on Linux, you get regular updates to the Java packages including these new data.
8. The updates do not always keep the previous behavior for both historical and future timestamps. So it may happen that parsing of the two timestamps around some time zone's change comparing them [may give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) when running on different versions of the software. That also applies to comparing between the affected time zone and other time zone.

   Should this cause a bug in your software, consider using some timestamp that does not have such complicated rules, like [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
9. Because of 7, for the future dates, we can't convert dates exactly with certainty. So, for instance, current parsing of *8524-02-17 12:00:00* may be off a couple of seconds from the future parsing.

#### JDK's APIs for this evolved with the contemporary needs

- The early Java releases had just `java.util.Date` which had a bit naive approach, assuming that there's just the year, month, day, and time. This quickly did not suffice.
- Also, the needs of the databases were different, so quite early, `java.sql.Date` was introduced, with its own limitations.
- Because neither covered different calendars and time zones well, the `Calendar` API was introduced.
- This still did not cover the complexity of the time zones. And yet, the mix of the above APIs was really a pain to work with. So as Java developers started working on global web applications, libraries that targeted most use cases, like JodaTime, got quickly popular. JodaTime was the de facto standard for about a decade.
- But the JDK did not integrate with JodaTime, so working with it was a bit cumbersome. So, after a very long discussion on how to approach the matter, [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) was created [mainly based on JodaTime](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983209).

### How to deal with it in Java's `java.time`

#### Determine what type to parse a timestamp to

When you are consuming a timestamp string, you need to know what information it contains. **This is the crucial point.** If you don't get this right, you end up with a cryptic exceptions like "Can't create Instant", "Zone offset missing", "unknown zone id", etc.

- [Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298214/unable-to-obtain-offsetdatetime-from-temporalaccessor)
- [Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596530/unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-temporalaccessor-using-datetimeformatter-and?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978897/datetimeparseexception-with-localdatetime-unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279066/instant-time-parsing-error-unable-to-obtain-instant-from-temporalaccessor)

**Does it contain the date and the time?**

1. **Does it have a time offset?**
   A time offset is the *+hh:mm* part. Sometimes, *+00:00* may be substituted with *Z* as 'Zulu time', `UTC` as Universal Time Coordinated, or *GMT* as Greenwich Mean Time. These also set the time zone.
   For these timestamps, you use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).
2. **Does it have a time zone?**
   For these timestamps, you use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).
   Zone is specified either by

   - name ("Prague", "Pacific Standard Time", "PST"), or
   - "zone ID" ("America/Los_Angeles", "Europe/London"), represented by [java.time.ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

   The list of time zones is compiled by a ["TZ database"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), backed by [ICAAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN).

   According to `ZoneId`'s javadoc, the zone id's can also somehow be specified as *Z* and offset. I'm not sure how this maps to real zones.

   If the timestamp, which only has a TZ, falls into a leap hour of time offset change, then it is ambiguous, and the interpretation is subject of `ResolverStyle`, see below.
3. **If it has neither**, then the missing context is assumed or neglected. And the consumer has to decide. So it needs to be parsed as `LocalDateTime` and converted to `OffsetDateTime` by adding the missing info:

   - You can *assume* that it is a UTC time. Add the UTC offset of 0 hours.
   - You can *assume* that it is a time of the place where the conversion is happening. Convert it by adding the system's time zone.
   - You can *neglect* and just use it as is. That is useful e.g. to compare or subtract two times (see [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)), or when you don't know and it doesn't really matter (e.g., local bus schedule).

**Partial time information**

- Based on what the timestamp contains, you can take `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `OffsetTime`, `MonthDay`, `Year`, or `YearMonth` out of it.

If you have the full information, you can get a [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). This is also internally used to convert between `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`.

#### Figure out how to parse it

There is an extensive documentation on [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which can both parse a timestamp string and format to string.

The [pre-created `DateTimeFormatter`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined) should cover more or less all standard timestamp formats. For instance, `ISO_INSTANT` can parse `2011-12-03T10:15:30.123457Z`.

If you have some special format, then you can [create your own DateTimeFormatter](https://www.baeldung.com/java-datetimeformatter) (which is also a parser).

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIMESTAMP_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .parseCaseInsensitive()
   .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SX"))
   .toFormatter();
```

I recommend to look at the source code of `DateTimeFormatter` and get inspired on how to build one using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. While you're there, also have a look at `ResolverStyle` which controls whether the parser is LENIENT, SMART or STRICT for the formats and ambiguous information.

#### TemporalAccessor

Now, the frequent mistake is to go into the complexity of `TemporalAccessor`. This comes from how the developers were used to work with `SimpleDateFormatter.parse(String)`. Right, `DateTimeFormatter.parse("...")` gives you `TemporalAccessor`.

```
// No need for this!
TemporalAccessor ta = TIMESTAMP_PARSER.parse("2011-... etc");
```

But, equipped with the knowledge from the previous section, you can conveniently parse into the type you need:

```
OffsetDateTime myTimestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30.123457Z", TIMESTAMP_PARSER);
```

You do not actually need to the `DateTimeFormatter` either. The types you want to parse have the `parse(String)` methods.

```
OffsetDateTime myTimestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30.123457Z");
```

Regarding `TemporalAccessor`, you can use it if you have a vague idea of what information there is in the string, and want to decide at runtime.

I hope I shed some light of understanding onto your soul :)

Note: There's a backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7: [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). For Android it has [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

**[3]** Not just that they are not stripes, but there also some weird extremes. For instance, some [neighboring Pacific Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#/media/File:Solar_time_vs_standard_time.png) have +14:00 and -11:00 time zones. That means, that while on one island, there is 1st May 3 PM, on another island not so far, it is still 30 April 12 PM (if I counted correctly :) )

Answer (score 6):

Get the current UTC time in the required format

```
// Current the UTC time
OffsetDateTime utc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

// Get LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime localDateTime = utc.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println("*************" + localDateTime);

// Formatted UTC time
DateTimeFormatter dTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(" formats as " + dTF.format(localDateTime));

// Get the UTC time for the current date
Date now = new Date();
LocalDateTime utcDateTimeForCurrentDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dTF2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(" formats as " + dTF2.format(utcDateTimeForCurrentDateTime));
```

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to note with `LocalDateTime.parse` is that you cannot use it with a custom formatter with only date formatter characters, such as `uuuuMMdd`. In this case, you should use `LocalDate.parse` instead. For example:

```
String s = "20210223";
        
// ok
LocalDate.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd"));
        
// java.time.format.DateTimeParseException
LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd"));
```

Comment: This is the one that got me... even if hh:mm:ss are supplied as all zeros, you still get the parse exception and can only parse the LocalDate portion... annoying.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers are good. The Java 8+ versions have these patterns for parsing and formatting time zones: `V`, `z`, `O`, `X`, `x`, `Z`.

Here's they are, for **parsing**, according to rules from the documentation:

```
   Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
   ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
   z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
   O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;
   X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   x       zone-offset                 offset-x          +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

But how about **formatting**?

Here's a sample for a date (assuming `ZonedDateTime`) that show these patters behavior for different formatting patters:

```java
// The helper function:
static void printInPattern(ZonedDateTime dt, String pattern) {
    System.out.println(pattern + ": " + dt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
}

// The date:
String strDate = "2020-11-03 16:40:44 America/Los_Angeles";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz");
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate, format);
// 2020-11-03T16:40:44-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

// Rules:
// printInPattern(dt, "V");     // exception!
printInPattern(dt, "VV");       // America/Los_Angeles
// printInPattern(dt, "VVV");   // exception!
// printInPattern(dt, "VVVV");  // exception!
printInPattern(dt, "z");        // PST
printInPattern(dt, "zz");       // PST
printInPattern(dt, "zzz");      // PST
printInPattern(dt, "zzzz");     // Pacific Standard Time
printInPattern(dt, "O");        // GMT-8
// printInPattern(dt, "OO");    // exception!
// printInPattern(dt, "OO0");   // exception!
printInPattern(dt, "OOOO");     // GMT-08:00
printInPattern(dt, "X");        // -08
printInPattern(dt, "XX");       // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "XXX");      // -08:00
printInPattern(dt, "XXXX");     // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "XXXXX");    // -08:00
printInPattern(dt, "x");        // -08
printInPattern(dt, "xx");       // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "xxx");      // -08:00
printInPattern(dt, "xxxx");     // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "xxxxx");    // -08:00
printInPattern(dt, "Z");        // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "ZZ");       // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "ZZZ");      // -0800
printInPattern(dt, "ZZZZ");     // GMT-08:00
printInPattern(dt, "ZZZZZ");    // -08:00
```

In the case of positive offset, the `+` sign character is used everywhere (where there is `-` now) and never omitted.

This well works for new `java.time` types. If you're about to use these for `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` - not all going to work as those types are broken (and so marked as deprecated, please don't use them).

Answer (score 3):

The **universal method**  looks as below. It works for:

- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
- yyyy-MM-dd HH
- yyyy-MM-dd

  ```
  public static final String DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_SSS = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";

  public LocalDateTime stringToLocalDateTime(String s){
      return LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_SSS.substring(0, s.length())));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take two questions, example string `"2014-04-08 12:30"`

> How can I obtain a LocalDateTime instance from the given string?

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

// Parsing or conversion
final LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-04-08 12:30", formatter)
```

`dt` should allow you to all date-time related operations

> How can I then convert the LocalDateTime instance back to a string with the same format?

```
final String date = dt.format(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it wonderful to cover multiple variants of date time formats like this:

```
final DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtfb = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
dtfb.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"))
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0);
```

Comment: ```
   public final static DateTimeFormatter TIMESTAMP_XX =
      new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern ("[[uuuu][-MM][-dd]][ [HH][:mm][:ss][.SSS]]")
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.YEAR            , 2020)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR   , 1)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH    , 1)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY     , 0)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR  , 0)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
      .parseDefaulting (ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND  , 0)
      .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already many good answers to this question. This answer shows how to use predefined `DateTimeFormatter`s to build a `DateTimeFormatter` which can parse the given date-time string.

However, formatting the obtained `LocalDateTime` using this `DateTimeFormatter` will return a string with time in `HH:mm:ss` format. To restrict the time string to `HH:mm` format, we still have to use the pattern `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm` as other answers have done.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        String strDateTime = "2014-04-08 12:30";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // However, formatting the obtained LocalDateTime using this DateTimeFormatter
        // will return a string with time in HH:mm:ss format. To restrict the time
        // string to HH:mm format, we still have to use the pattern, uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm as
        // other answers have done.
        String strDateTimeFormatted = ldt.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(strDateTimeFormatted);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        strDateTimeFormatted = ldt.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(strDateTimeFormatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2014-04-08T12:30
2014-04-08 12:30:00
2014-04-08 12:30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/kkeDDp)

**Note**: Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

When I have a variable of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` to get the date with a desirable format and I don't want to use intermediate classes, I just do:

```java
LocalDateTime nowDate = LocalDateTime.now();
String nowDateInString = nowDate.toString().substring(0,16).replace("T", " ");
```

The value of nowDateInString : 2023-10-27 11:17

You can adjust the value in 'substring' to retrieve what you want.

I would like to point out that this is not a suitable method in every situation.