# DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-07 12:18:16' could not be parsed

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have following code to convert an Instant to String then convert it back to I

```
String timestampString = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
LOGGER.info("timestampString: " + timestampString);

Instant instant =
    LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

it print the timestampString as:   `2019-06-07 12:45:57`

and failed at parse the string:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-07 12:45:57' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=45, HourOfAmPm=0, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=57, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},ISO resolved to 2019-06-07 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

why it cannot parse it even though that's the same format I convert the timestamp to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor on format ddMMyyyyhhmmss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394931/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-tem). And/or of [Converting text to instant [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439563/converting-text-to-instant).

Comment: Tip: more tags will help attract more people who know about the subject that you’re asking about.

Comment: Basically, you want `HH` rather than `hh`. `hh` is *12-hour* hour of day; you want the 24-hour hour of day.

Comment: I do wonder *why* you're converting it to a string and back, mind you - note that `LocalDateTime.now()` uses the system time zone, whereas you're then claiming it's in UTC. If you could provide more context for what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you with more than the parsing.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to track a moment, as explained in its Javadoc. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use HH for hour of day instead of hh

The problem that you are asking about is that you are using lowercase `hh` in your format pattern string (both times). You need uppercase `HH` for hour day from 00 through 23. `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12. So what went wrong was that java.time didn’t know whether `12` in your string referred to 12 AM or 12 PM and refused to make a guess for you.

If you read the exception message closely you will also notice that it says that `HourOfAmPm=0` was parsed. It doesn’t say `HourOfDay`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String timestampString = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
    System.out.println("timestampString: " + timestampString);

    Instant instant = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, formatter)
            .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    System.out.println("instant: " + instant);
```

When I ran this snippet just now, I got this output:

> ```
> timestampString: 2019-06-08 19:22:51
> instant: 2019-06-08T19:22:51Z
> ```

This is *wrong*! I ran the snippet around 17:22 UTC, not 19:22. Since Denmark is still using summer time (damn), the local time here was 19:22, which was used for the result and translated into the same wall clock time in UTC, not the same instant. You should *always* pass your desired time zone to the `now` method to avoid such bugs. Since you wanted UTC:

```
    String timestampString = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(formatter);
```

> ```
> timestampString: 2019-06-08 17:27:57
> instant: 2019-06-08T17:27:57Z
> ```

Still better, don’t use `LocalDateTime` for holding something that you want to use as a moment in time. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` instead.

There is more information on using `hh`, `HH` or `kk` for formatting and parsing hour values [in this question and its answers: Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat). The question is asking about the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`,  but the answers are valid for `DateTimeFormatter` too.