# Convert string into LocalDateTime

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin

I have the following String:

`18/07/2019 16:20`

I try to convert this string into `LocalDateTime` with the following code:

```
val stringDate = expiration_button.text.toString()
val date = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")).toString()
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18/07/2019 04:30:00'
>   could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from
>   TemporalAccessor

What I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe this one can help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-07 12:18:16' could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500476/datetimeparseexception-text-2019-06-07-121816-could-not-be-parsed)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this will answer your question:

```
val stringDate = expiration_button.text.toString()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
val dt = LocalDate.parse(stringDate, formatter);
```

Edit 1:

It's probably crashing because you are using a 12hr Hour, instead of a 24hr pattern.

Changing the hour to 24hr pattern by using a capital H should fix it:

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Comment: It works with LocalDate, but I need LocalDateTime because with this I'm losing minutes and seconds. if I change LocalDate for LocalDateTime it crashes.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: The problem was the hour. I had `hh` instead of `HH`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use below to convert the time from String to LocalDateTime, but make sure you are getting the time in String form.

```
String str = "2016-03-04 11:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Btw, If your String contains seconds as well like "2016-03-04 11:30: 40", then you can change your date time format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" as shown below:

```
String str = "2016-03-04 11:30: 40";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your datetime format to `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"` and provide a string date with additional AM/PM information, e.g. `val stringDate = "18/07/2019 04:20 PM"` or just use the 24 hour format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`.

Comment: If on one hand the string is given, `18/07/2019 16:20`, modifying it is this way is not trivial. If on the other hand it is possible to get a different string, I would suggest a string in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so `2019-07-18T16:20`. `LocalDateTime` will parse such a string without any explicit formatter, simplifying things.

Answer (score -2):

You may try using "-" instead of "/" on the date.