# DateTimeFormatter is not working with ofPattern nor OFFSET

Tags: java, datetime-format

I try to format a Datestring to OffsetDateTime with the Java buildIn DateTimeFormatter. My DateTimeFormatter does not work as expected.

The String is: "2018-11-12T14:55:17 +0100"

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZZZZZ");
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
```

I expected, that with the DateTimeFormater I will get a proper OffsetDateTime. may one can help me out of this situation?

Comment: Related, and possibly a duplicate of: (1) [Java: Date parsing, why do I get an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666263/java-date-parsing-why-do-i-get-an-error) (2) [Not able to convert the string to date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988150/not-able-to-convert-the-string-to-date-on-android)

Comment: And for the case of `hh` partly a duplicate of [DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-07 12:18:16' could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500476/datetimeparseexception-text-2019-06-07-121816-could-not-be-parsed) or [Convert string into LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096793/convert-string-into-localdatetime)

Comment: It’s unclear whether you were trying to *parse* (convert string to `OffsetDateTime`) or *format* (the opposite conversion)?

Answer (score 1):

No need of any formatter you can directly parse the string into `OffsetDateTime`, remove the space and add colon between minutes and seconds

```
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-11-12T14:55:17+01:00");
System.out.println(time);
```

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss X");
```

Big HH and the X *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question (you may also accept your own answer). I get `2019-08-04T09:24:36 +02`. Two points: (1) According to ISO 8601 there should not be a space between `ss` and `X`. (2) For four digit offset, hours and minutes, as in `+0200`, use two `X`s. So `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX`.