# ZonedDateTime format and parsing exception with “z” in format pattern

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime, datetimeparseexception

I have a problem with parsing `ZonedDateTime`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddzhh:mm");
ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
```

This results in an error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
    Text '2022-05-24UTC12:15' could not be parsed at index 10
```

whats wrong with this code?

Comment: The pattern is wrong…

Comment: Give this a try!
[zoneddatetime-parse-method-in-java-with-examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zoneddatetime-parse-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: `2022-05-24UTC12:15` — What a weird format. Is there a particular reason why this format is used?

Comment: @MCEmperor well 3rd party has such weird formatting, and are using our API, I was suprised with this format also

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Java 17 I get a completely different exception: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-05-24UTC12:15' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=15, HourOfAmPm=0},ISO,Etc/UTC resolved to 2022-05-24 of type java.time.format.Parsed`.

Comment: In your format pattern string you need upper case `HH` for hour of day. See for example [DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-07 12:18:16' could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500476/datetimeparseexception-text-2019-06-07-121816-could-not-be-parsed).

Comment: What is your locale? Could it be that UTC is called something else in your default locale??

Comment: Surprise: I can reproduce your problem in German locale even though your formatter still *prints* `UTC` for Etc/UTC time zone. Might look like a bug in java.time (I am still using Java 17).

Comment: I should say it’s a bug. I did a fast search and didn’t find it documented, though. Using German locale `DateTimeFormatter` can parse `2022-05-24UTC` using pattern `yyyy-MM-ddz` and `UTC12:15` using pattern `zHH:mm` but not `2022-05-24UTC12:15` using pattern `yyyy-MM-ddzHH:mm`. With non-German locales there isn’t any problem. Consider reporting it.

Comment: Yeah, @OleV.V. it's the German locale that was implicitly considered when I tried it without explicitly providing a locale. Works with `Locale.ENGLISH`, for example…

Comment: For a workaround just specify a non-German locale on your formatter, for example `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-ddzHH:mm", Locale.ROOT);`.

Comment: Secondary conclusions still worth noting: (1) It’s always a good idea to specify locale explicitly on your formatter. (2) That 3rd party — and everyone exchanging date and time data — ought to learn about [the ISO 8601 standard for doing so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character `z` should be able to parse `"UTC"` (in most `Locale`s) because *UTC* is considered a *time-zone ID* and a *time-zone name* in `java.time`. A `VV` can parse *time-zone ids* while `z`can parse *time-zone-names* according to the [JavaDocs of `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), here's the relevant part of the docs:

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
(…)

V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST

(…)
```

That means you can parse it using the character `V` without providing a specific `Locale` to your `DateTimeFormatter`. You will have to put two of them (`VV`) or you will get a nice `IllegalArgumentException` with the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern letter count must be 2: V
```

If you still want to use `z`, provide a `Locale` that considers `UTC` an abbreviation of *Universal Time Coordinated*, the *Central European Summer Time* is an abbreviation that definitely changes among different `Locale`s, e.g.

- English: `CEST`
- German:  `MESZ`

Other `Locale`s might have different abbreviations, which makes me wonder if your `Locale` actually even has a different one for `UTC`.
Provide `Locale.ENGLISH`, for example and it should parse successfully.

You should provide one anyway because if you don't, the `DateTimeFormatter` will implicitly use the default `Locale` of your (Java Virtual) machine.

So you can try this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-ddVVHH:mm");
```

or this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-ddzHH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

both should be able to parse an input like `"2022-05-24UTC12:15"` **if you use `HH` instead of `hh`** for hours of day (`hh` = 12h format, `HH` = 24h format).

Comment: thanks, hmm this works right with UTC, but what if I would like to parse " Text '2022-05-24CEST12:15' could not be parsed at index 10" ?

Comment: I want also CEST instead of UTC for example

Comment: I think thats why I used z :) but its not good for UTC then

Comment: yyyy-MM-ddzHH:mm is perfect then for me

Comment: I don't think `"2022-05-24CEST12:15"` can be parsed at all with a `DateTimeFormatter` built with a single `z`, at least it doesn't work on my machine. However, `2022-05-24CET12:15` (no `S`, only `CET`) can be parsed with your formatter.

Comment: Yes, @OleV.V. if I apply a `Locale` it will even parse `CEST` ;-), **but not without** and the locales `GERMAN` and `GERMANY` don't work.

Comment: That‘s why it does not work without a locale on my machine…

Comment: @FrancMo Beware of 2-4 letter pseudo time zones like `CET`, `CEST`, `CST`, `IST`. These are not real time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique! They should be used only for presentation to the user, never for data exchange.

Comment: @BasilBourque well I dont like this format but its connected to some 3rd party, thats why.

Comment: @FrancMo  When you receive such a string with `IST`, how will you know if it means India Standard Time or Ireland Standard time? If you receive a string with `CST`, how will you know if it means Central Standard Time or China Standard Time?

Answer (score -3):

Yes it's because of formatter pattern, i suggest to use the code below :

```
    final DateTimeFormatter format
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime
            .parse("2022-05-24 14:30:30 -01:00", format);
    
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);

    ZonedDateTime localTimeline = zonedDateTime
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    // for the local timezone
    System.out.println(localTimeline);
```

Comment: Well, this code won't help the question asker, because their input text is different.

Comment: If we want to suggest a different format - which makes sense - I think we should suggest ISO 8601, the international standard.