# How do you set a date in yyyy-MM-dd format and then be able to print it out later on in the same format in Java 1.8?

Tags: java, date, java-8

In the following code:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String zdtString = FORMATTER.format(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdtString);
```

you will see it prints out the current date in yyyy-DD-mm format.  Since this question was posted on July 17, 2021, it printed:

```
2021-07-17
```

But now I would like to change the date to something different (like 1994-03-24).

So I tried:

```
    DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("1994-03-24", FORMATTER);
    String zdtString = FORMATTER.format(zdt2);
    System.out.println(zdtString);
```

But then I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1994-03-24' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 1994-03-24 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at javaapplication5.JavaApplication5.main(JavaApplication5.java:48)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 1994-03-24 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:565)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 1994-03-24 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZoneId.from(ZoneId.java:466)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:553)
    ... 4 more
```

How do I set my own dates to something other than current date?

Comment: For me finding the linked original question was not hard. Wondering how hard you searched before asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor using DateTimeFormatter and ZonedDateTime in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596530/unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-temporalaccessor-using-datetimeformatter-and)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1994-03-24 does not have timezone information and therefore it can not be parsed into `ZonedDateTime` until you provide the timezone information. Also, you will need to default the time units.

1994-03-24 can be directly parsed into `LocalDate` as the modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1994-03-24"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1994-03-24
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/pkqC6O)

Demo of parsing with default time unit and a specific timezone:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("u-M-d[ H]")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)                                
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)
                                .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
                                

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("1994-03-24", dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1994-03-24T00:00Z[Europe/London]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YLnJVV)

**Note:** `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returns the JVM's `ZoneId`. Replace it with the applicable `ZoneId` e.g. `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`. Also, notice the optional pattern inside the square bracket which has been defaulted to 0.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: You need to move `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` to *after* the pattern. Otherwise, a string with an hour component cannot be parsed.

Comment: @MCEmperor - Thanks for the catch. As far as I can recall this is the second time on SO I have done this mistake in a hurry. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Well, I noticed because I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472713/java-time-format-datetimeparseexception-text-could-not-be-parsed-at-index/68472816#68472816) a question with the same problem.