# date object string to date in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have string like below and I need to convert this as a date in java

```
"Tue Sep 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014"
```

This is a string representation of the java date object. I get it as a string where I need to parse it like "30 Sep 2014"

I thought if I could get this as a date object I can get whatever format I want using simpledateformat. But the problem is how do I get the date Object from this string

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` has a `parse()` method too

Comment: Down-vote from me. I can't imagine how you wouldn't spot the `parse()` method with even a tiny bit of prior research.

Answer (score 1):

The format you're looking for is this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

You can check all the valid formats here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [SimpleDateFomrat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the string into date:

```
String s = "Tue Sep 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.parse(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date convertDate(final String dateValue) {
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(dateValue);
        return date;
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[the java 8 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)... and you will find much more entries already exist in stackoverflow.

Comment: Please don't just link to other answers or questions in your answer. That's what comments are for (or flagging).