# Timestamp string to timestamp in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have the following string "2015-04-02 11:52:00+02" and I need to parse it in Java to a Timestamp. 
I tried all sorts of formats including

```
SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+Z");
```

but nothing seems to work - I keep getting a ParseException

Can anyone help?

I need something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+Z");


Timestamp t = new Timestamp(mdyFormat.parse("2015-04-02 11:52:00+02").getTime());
```

Comment: Post Your StackTrace !!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-04-02 11:52:00+02"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.......Main.main(Main.java:45)

Comment: Not sure if you can use Java 8, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8) may help you.

Comment: If using [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), be aware that the original version of java.time in Java 8 had a bug where it failed to parse offset-from-UTC values of just hours without minutes. I'm referring to the `+02` in the Question above, as opposed to hours:minutes value of `+02:00`. That hours-only value is indeed valid (defined by [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) but does not parse with early versions of java.time. May be fixed in later updates to Java 8, though I've not tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try This

```
String str="2009-12-31 23:59:59 +0100";
                               /\
                               ||
                      Provide Space while providing timeZone

SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(mdyFormat.parse(str));
```

**Output**

```
Fri Jan 01 04:29:59 IST 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

try `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX"`

`Z` stand for timezone in the following format: `+0800`

`X` stand for timezone in the following format: `+08`

Examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.Timestamp objects don't have time zones - they are instants in time, like java.util.Date

So try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(mdyFormat.parse("2015-04-02 11:52:00").getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

Replace that SPACE in the middle with a `T` and you have a valid standard ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) string format that can be parsed directly by either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). Search StackOverflow for hundreds of examples.

If using java.time, read my comment on Question about a bug when parsing hours-only offset value.

Example in Joda-Time 2.7.

```
String inputRaw = "2015-04-02 11:52:00+02";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" );
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );  // Specify desired time zone adjustment.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, zone );
```