# How to replace characters in a String for filename

Tags: java

I'm using the LocalDateTime.now() method to get the current time and date for the filenames for file reports, and colons are  not allowed in filename.

How can I replace every colon (":") with a period (".") in the String so it's acceptable to set as a filename?

Comment: See here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replace will solve this for you.

```
String date = "01:02:1990";
System.out.println(date); //01:02:1990
String amendedDate = date.replace(":", ".");
System.out.println(amendedDate); //01.02.1990
```

Comment: i know op asked a low level api question, but formatters exist to format dates

Answer (score 6):

use format() method

[How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm");
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "2015-07-07 12.30"
```

http://ideone.com/bQGPE3

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [string replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).