# Is there any way to convert ZoneId to ZoneOffset in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

I have an epoch second and a *zoneId* (see `method1` below).

It can be convert to `LocalDateTime` with system default zoneId, but I don't find the way to convert epoch second to `LocalDateTime` (see  `method2` below), because there is no `ZoneOffset.systemDefault`. I think it's obscure.

```
import java.time.{Instant, LocalDateTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset}

val epochSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000

// method1
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond), ZoneId.systemDefault())

// method2
LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond, 0, ZoneOffset.MAX)
```

---

### NOTE

The source code presented above is [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/).

Comment: What language/dialect are you using to make the bulk import `import java.time.{Instant, LocalDateTime, ZoneId, ZoneOffset}` work? It's an `unexpected token` for me in Java 11.

Comment: Can be Scala, but that's not really important here

Comment: I have discussed the theory behind `java.time` at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508200/145989

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Here is how you can get `ZoneOffset` from `ZoneId`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now(); //can be LocalDateTime
ZoneId systemZone = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // my timezone
ZoneOffset currentOffsetForMyZone = systemZone.getRules().getOffset(instant);
```

NB: `ZoneId` can have different offset depending on point in time and the history of the particular place. So choosing different Instants would result in different offsets.

NB2: `ZoneId.of()` can return a `ZoneOffset` instead of `ZoneId` if `UTC+3`/`GMT+2`/etc is passed as opposed to a time zone like `Africa/Cairo`. So if UTC/GMT offsets are passed then historical/geographical/daylight-saving information of the `Instant` won't be taken into account - you'll simply work with the specified offset.

Comment: This gives incorrect value if current instant is in DST, but at the moment of calculation it was without DST

Comment: I checked that and it works depending on another condition. Updated answer with that.

Answer (score 55):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
```

…of current default time zone…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.systemDefault() 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Stanislav Bshkyrtsev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37501492/642706) correctly and directly answers your Question.

But, there are larger issues involved, as suggested in the [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626913/642706).

### `LocalDateTime`

> I don't find the way to convert epoch second to LocalDateTime

`LocalDateTime` purposely has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Not likely what you want. The `Local…` means *any* locality, not any one particular locality. This class does *not* represent a moment, only *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe).

### `Instant`

No need to start with epoch seconds if you are trying to get current time. Get the current `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Inside of that `Instant` is a count of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)-from-epoch. But we do not really care.

See also, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see that moment through the lens of a particular region’s wall-clock time, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

As a shortcut, you can do directly to the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

A `ZonedDateTime` has an `Instant` within it. Call `zdt.toInstant()` to get the same moment in time as a basic value in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Same number of nanoseconds-since-epoch either way, as a `ZonedDateTime` or as a `Instant`.

### Seconds-since-epoch given

If you are given a count of seconds-since-epoch, and the epoch is the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), then feed that number to `Instant`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = 1_484_063_246L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( secondsSinceEpoch ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 49):

There is no one-to-one mapping. A ZoneId defines a geographic extent in which a set of different ZoneOffsets is used over time. If the timezone uses daylight saving time, its ZoneOffset will be different between summer and winter.

Furthermore, the daylight saving time rules may have changed over time, so the ZoneOffset could be different for e.g. 13/10/2015 compared to 13/10/1980.

So you can only find the ZoneOffset for a ZoneId on a particular Instant.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Comment: I know that, but how is it done?If I know the LocaDate and have a ZoneId, how do I convert it into a ZoneOffset. My use-case is a string that contains a time and a zone. I want to parse the string into an OffsetTime, without droping the zone information.

Answer (score 12):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#ofEpochSecond-long-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-) says, "This is primarily intended for low-level conversions rather than general application usage."

Going via `Instant` makes perfect sense to me - your epoch second is effectively a different representation of an `Instant`, so convert to an `Instant` and then convert that into a particular time zone.

Answer (score 9):

I hope the first two lines of my solution below are helpful.  My problem was I had a `LocalDateTime` and the name of a time zone, and I needed an `instant` so I could build a `java.util.Date`, because that's what MongoDB wanted.  My code is Scala, but it's so close to Java here I think there should be no problem understanding it:

```
val zid = ZoneId.of(tzName)                                // "America/Los_Angeles"
val zo: ZoneOffset = zid.getRules.getOffset(localDateTime) // ⇒ -07:00
                                         // 2017-03-16T18:03

val odt = OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, zo) // ⇒ 2017-03-16T18:03:00-07:00
val instant = odt.toInstant                    // ⇒ 2017-03-17T01:03:00Z
val issued = Date.from(instant)
```

Comment: I posted this answer here because this was the page that came up when I was searching for a way to do what I eventually figured out.

Answer (score 3):

The following returns the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get standard time in this time zone:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")).getRawOffset()
```

Comment: localZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(TimeZone.getTimeZone(localTimeZone).getRawOffset / 1000)

Answer (score 3):

> I have an epoch second and a zoneId. Is there any way to convert ZoneId to ZoneOffset in java 8?

1. Get `ZonedDateTime` from epoch second and Zone Id
2. Get `ZoneOffset` from `ZonedDateTime`

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get ZonedDateTime from epoch second and Zone Id
        ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1597615462L).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        // Get ZoneOffset from ZonedDateTime
        ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();

        System.out.println(offset);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we use. First convert zone id to timezone, then get the offset in millis, then convert to seconds, then create a ZoneOffset.

```
public static final ZoneOffset toOffset(ZoneId zoneId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(zoneId)
            .map(TimeZone::getTimeZone)
            .map(TimeZone::getRawOffset)
            .map(Duration::ofMillis)
            .map(Duration::getSeconds)
            .map(Number::intValue)
            .map(ZoneOffset::ofTotalSeconds)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the default zone offset

```
ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it without creating an Instant or such objects to pull it out.

```
public static ZoneOffset offset() {
    return offset(ZoneId.systemDefault());                 // Default system zone id
}
public static ZoneOffset offset(ZoneId id) {
    return ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(
            TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getRawOffset()        // Returns offset in milliseconds 
        )
    );
}
```