# Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

When I do this

```
String datum = "20130419233512";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
OffsetDateTime datetime = OffsetDateTime.parse(datum, formatter);
```

I get the following exception:

```
    java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20130419233512' could not be parsed: 
Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1366407312},ISO,Europe/Berlin resolved 
to 2013-04-19T23:35:12 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

How can I parse my datetime string so that it is interpreted as always being from the timezone "Europe/Berlin" ?

Comment: I have discussed the theory behind `java.time` at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508200/145989

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that there is a difference between what a `ZoneId` is and a `ZoneOffset` is. To create a `OffsetDateTime`, you need an zone offset. But [there is no one-to-one mapping between a `ZoneId` and a `ZoneOffset`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32626733/1743880) because it actually depends on the current daylight saving time. For the same `ZoneId` like "Europe/Berlin", there is one offset for summer and a different offset for winter.

For this case, it would be easier to use a `ZonedDateTime` instead of an `OffsetDateTime`. During parsing, the `ZonedDateTime` will correctly be set to the `"Europe/Berlin"` zone id and the offset will also be set according to the daylight saving time in effect for the date to parse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String datum = "20130419233512";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    ZonedDateTime datetime = ZonedDateTime.parse(datum, formatter);

    System.out.println(datetime.getZone()); // prints "Europe/Berlin"
    System.out.println(datetime.getOffset()); // prints "+02:00" (for this time of year)
}
```

Note that if you really want an `OffsetDateTime`, you can use [`ZonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime--) to convert a `ZonedDateTime` into an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: I like that you do this in one step, rather than in two like I showed.  I'll leave my answer since both will work, but I'd recommend yours for the green checkmark. :)

Comment: Since I need OffsetDateTime I use now `OffsetDateTime datetime = ZonedDateTime.parse(datum, formatter).toOffsetDateTime();` .

Comment: @asmaier Yep, that's what I commented also. You can use that to convert to an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: The documentation of that method says "The zone ID is ignored". What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 15):

There's no offset in your source data, and thus `OffsetDateTime` is not the correct type to use during parsing.

Instead, use a `LocalDateTime`, since that is the type that most closely resembles the data you have.  Then use `atZone` to assign it a time zone, and if you still need an `OffsetDateTime`, you can call `toOffsetDateTime` from there.

```
String datum = "20130419233512";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(datum, formatter);
ZonedDateTime zoned = datetime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
OffsetDateTime result = zoned.toOffsetDateTime();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for me. I somehow assumed the OffsetDateTime.parse() method would do these steps internally for me.

Comment: This one works perfectly, I somehow thought the same thing as OP. This looks neat!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I faced similar issue when I made a parsing from String to ZonedDateTime and needed to get OffsetDateTime.

There is excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071826/16543524
(can't make comments)