# Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing a Date

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

With Java 1.8.0_51 the following code (taken from [Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298214/unable-to-obtain-offsetdatetime-from-temporalaccessor))

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("20151113", formatter).toOffsetDateTime();
System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
```

throws an exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20151113' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Berlin resolved to 2015-11-13 of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
```

What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: I have discussed the theory behind `java.time` at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508200/145989

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are forgetting to set a time.

If you compare [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35298482/1743880) with your code, you can notice that the only difference is that the time information missing. A `ZonedDateTime` contains a time information and since your current formatter does not handle it, an instance of `ZonedDateTime` can't be formed.

You can also see it in the stacktrace, that contains

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Berlin resolved to 2015-11-13 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:560)
    ... 5 more
```

Depending on what you want, you could build a custom formatter with [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and call [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) to provide a default values for each time chrono fields. If you want to default to midnight, you can set [`NANO_OF_DAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#NANO_OF_DAY) to 0. A sample example would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                                      .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
                                      .toFormatter()
                                      .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("20151113", formatter).toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
}
```

---

Another possible solution would be to parse the text as a `LocalDate` and then construct a `ZoneDateTime` with it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse("20151113", formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(parsed, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    // get OffsetDateTime similarly
}
```

Comment: So I cannot set a default time for my DateTimeFormatter as I can set a default time zone?

Comment: @asmaier Yes, this is `parseDefaulting` purpose. I edited with an example.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 8 `java.time.*` package is a very strict package. It doesn't allow flexibility between types and inputs - if you want a `ZonedDateTime` object, you must construct it from an input that has a time zone, a date & a time.

If you want to use *just* a date to construct an object it has to be of a type that doesn't have a time field, specifically, `LocalDate`.

Comment: But a LocalDate does not have a timezone. And there is no `ZonedDate` only without a time.

Comment: @Tunaki - Correct. Personally I don't find it very comfortable to work with the package for these reasons exactly. It could be argued that "a date has no timezone", but practically it's useful at times...

Comment: I found a solution with LocalDate, too: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"); OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = LocalDate.parse("20151113", formatter).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toOffsetDateTime();` But I prefer the solution from @Tunaki, because all the configuration for the parsing is done via the formatter.

Comment: @asmaier - that's OK. My answer explains the issue, it doesn't choose a solution. Choose the solution that works best for you...