# How to convert LocalDateTime to GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, java-time

Why is it possible to pass a `LocalDateTime` object into the `ZonedDateTime.from()` method, if it's not possible to parse a simple `DateTime`, as follows?

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59")));
}
```

Result:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-08-31T23:00:59 of type java.time.LocalDateTime
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:565)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert to a `GregorianCalendar`, or are you asking why it allows you to pass an implementation of the `TemporalAccessor` interface and only complains about it in runtime?

Comment: GeorgianCalendar requires a timezone so actually you can do `GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59+00:00"));` providing a timezone. `ZonedDateTime.from` can fail for different types of input and that mentioned in javadoc.

Comment: The diagram showing conversions from old date-time classes to java.time in [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155) to the [Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154) may be useful. Also find example code converting in both directions.

Comment: @BasilBourque that's a really great diagram!

Answer (score 14):

> Why is it possible to pass a LocalDateTime object into the
> ZonedDateTime.from() method if it's not possible to parse a simple
> datetime?

Both [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) implement the interface called [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html), which extends [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html).

`LocalDateTime` is datetime *without* a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30

`ZonedDateTime` is datetime *with* a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

Now, if you see the implementation of `from(TemporalAccessor temporal)` method that is expecting the [TemporalAccessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html)… Both `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` implements the method of super interface `TemporalAccessor` (`Temporal extends TemporalAccessor`), which is normal (i.e. has a polymorphic behavior) to allow us to pass both the local as well as zoned datetime.

Code:

```
public static ZonedDateTime from(final TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    if (temporal instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
        return (ZonedDateTime) temporal;
    }

    try {
        final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.from(temporal);

        if (temporal.isSupported(INSTANT_SECONDS)) {
            long epochSecond = temporal.getLong(INSTANT_SECONDS);
            int nanoOfSecond = temporal.get(NANO_OF_SECOND);

            return create(epochSecond, nanoOfSecond, zone);
        } else {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(temporal);
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(temporal);

            return of(date, time, zone);
        }
    } catch (final DateTimeException exception) {
        throw new DateTimeException(
            "Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: " +
            temporal + " of type " + temporal.getClass().getName(),
            exception
        );
    }
}
```

Now, we come to your problem.

You are passing `LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59")` to the `from(TemporalAccessor temporal)` method. So, the temporal is not an instance of `ZonedDateTime`, it comes `ZoneId zone = ZoneId.from(temporal);`.

So, your are getting the error since the `LocalDateTime` does not contain the
timezone.

How to solve the issue?

Use the Zone ID with the `ZonedDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId);
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

with JUnit test

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    GregorianCalendar.from(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59").atZone(zoneId));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You will have to provide the `ZoneId` as well. I will have to look up on the behavior as to why this is. I will edit and post as soon as I see it.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-08-31T23:00:59");
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
System.out.println(gc);
```

This results:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1472664659000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=35,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=31,DAY_OF_YEAR=244,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=0,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

*Edits:*
Just came across this interesting [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944270/unable-to-obtain-zoneddatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-a-date)...

> The Java 8 java.time.* package is a very strict package. It doesn't allow flexibility between types and inputs - if you want a ZonedDateTime object, you must construct it from an input that has a time zone, a date & a time.