# How can I convert Java ZonedDateTime to OffsetDateTime with default time zone offset?

Tags: java, java-time

Say I have a ZonedDateTime of `2018-10-30T18:04:58.874Z` : 
How can I convert this to OffsetDateTime `2018-10-30T13:04:58.874-05:00`

I'd prefer the offset to be the default/system offset, for example pulled from `OffsetDateTime.now()`.

Comment: What methods of `ZonedDateTime` do you think can be useful here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your `ZonedDateTime` you need to specify in which other zone you want your `OffsetDateTime`, precise the zone and them use `.toOffsetDateTime()` :

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-10-30T18:04:58.874Z");
System.out.println(z); //2018-10-30T18:04:58.874Z

OffsetDateTime o = z.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC-5")).toOffsetDateTime();
System.out.println(o); //2018-10-30T13:04:58.874-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This will shift the time zone from current/now:

```
someOffsetDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset())
```

Comment: This in general seems wrong to me: the offset can change if DST takes place and now() and  tha actual date under parse can require different offsets

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to do it is as follows:

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-10-30T18:04:58.874Z");
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(date.toInstant());
ZonedDateTime dateInMyZone = date.withZoneSameInstant(offset)
```

getting it from now() will give you a possibly wrong result casue the offset can change during the year due to DST