# Difference between give date (UTC date) and current date in days using Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

Input to my method will be a `String` containing a date in UTC. I need to compare the input date with current date and time and check the difference between two dates. The result should be in days.

I tried the following with no success.

```
String dateString = "2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 UTC";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
OffsetDateTime parsedDate  = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter1);
System.out.println("======================:"+parsedDate.format(formatter1));


OffsetDateTime currentUTC = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("Until (with crono): " + parsedDate.until(currentUTC, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

I need the result in an `int` (i.e., number of days).

The line `OffsetDateTime parsedDate  = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter1);` throws an exception with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 UTC' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1560875021},ISO,UTC resolved to 2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1959)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1894)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at thiagarajanramanathan.misc.App.main(App.java:86)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1560875021},ISO,UTC resolved to 2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:235)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1560875021},ISO,UTC resolved to 2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.ZoneOffset.from(ZoneOffset.java:348)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:359)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Have you tried java.time package?

Comment: Actually DateTimeFormatter and OffsetDateTime both are from java.time package.

Comment: Does your code give you what you want? If not, how does observed result differ? Please quote any error message or stack trace verbatim. Thank you.

Comment: The result of running your code depends entirely on the instant it's run, and where it runs. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), replacing the use of `OffsetDateTime.now()` with a constant value so the question has meaning and value for other visitors (especially ones in the more distant future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from this thread: [Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298214/unable-to-obtain-offsetdatetime-from-temporalaccessor)
                                                   I changed the following lines:

```
//OffsetDateTime parsedDate  = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter1);
ZonedDateTime parsedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter1);
```

When your code is run with this modification, I could get the following results

for "2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 UTC" :

```
======================:2019-06-17T16:23:41.575 UTC
Until (with crono): 0
```

Since it's less than 24 hours, it returns 0

for "2019-06-17T16:23:41.575 UTC" :

```
======================:2019-06-17T16:23:41.575 UTC
Until (with crono): 1
```

Similarly, since it's over 24 hours but under 2 days, it returns 1.

I think this is what you want. Please try it and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It works. This is what I was expecting. Thank you @AntiqTech

Answer (score 1):

## Parsing

I would simplify the parsing if your input by getting it to comply with the ISO 8601 standard.

```
String input = "2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 UTC".replace( " UTC", "Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

## Days as 24-hour chunks

If your definition of elapsed days is 24-hour chunks of time, use `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instant , Instant.now() ;
long days = d.toDays() ;
```

## Days according to calendar

If you want a count of days elapsed as seen on the calendar, meaning dates rather than 24-hour chunks of time, you must specify a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the dates.

```
LocalDate start = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate stop = now.toLocalDate() ;
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

### The difference between an time zone and an offset

You have got two good answers already. You are touching on an interesting and a bit tricky part of java.time, so I should like to make my contribution too. My key point is that **a time zone and a UTC offset are not the same**. To obtain an `OffsetDateTime` you need an offset. You provide a time zone through the call `.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` on the formatter, but it doesn’t help you. Yes, you and I know that UTC is the base of all offsets and therefore itself defines an offset of 0. But Java didn’t discover that from your code.

I admit I was surprised to discover that the following simple change was enough that your code runs on Java 9:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter1
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'")
                    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

However on Java 8 I still get the same exception as before. The output I got on Java 9.0.4 was:

> ```
> ======================:2019-06-18T16:23:41.575 UTC
> Until (with crono): 0
> ```

The only change is that I am now passing a `ZoneOffset` rather than a `ZoneId` object to `withZone` (this is possible because `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`).

A formatter that works on Java 8 too is one where we supply a default offset. For that we need a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendLiteral(" UTC")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter();
```

Yet another and perhaps simpler option would be to parse into a `LocalDateTime` first (which requires neither offset nor time zone) and then convert to `OffsetDateTime` by calling `.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Comment: final DateTimeFormatter formatter1
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS 'UTC'")
                    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);  The above code snipped (ZoneOffset instead of ZoneId) is working perfectly on Java 8.