# Localized name of ZoneId's ID

Tags: java, java-8, timezone

I have a list of time zones that I want the user to choose from. So, I thought I can just call `java.time.ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` and use the method `getDisplayName` on them. This results in a lot of duplicate entries like

> Central European Time

Even if I add the time zone offset they are not unqiue. However, the ID of a `ZoneId` distinguishes the entries but **how can I localize them**? The IDs are always in English like

> Europe/Rome

Comment: I doubt you can. They're supposed to be unique identifiers.

Comment: @shmosel, do you have any idea how to make a time zone selection suitable to users language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to get a localized version of the display name by calling `getDisplayName` on a `ZoneId` instance. That would require iteration over the result of `getAvailableZoneIds()`:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
        .map(ZoneId::of)
        .map(zid -> zid.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.GERMAN))
        .distinct()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note the `TextStyle` argument to change the size of each zone's title and the `.distinct()` method to get unique results.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but does that really allow the user to pick the right time zone? I mean, are the offsets always the same for time zones with the same display name?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Yes timezone name allows picking the right timezone. But the offset changes twice a year if daylight saving is observed. That's why you [need a date/instant to convert ZoneId to ZoneOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32626733/1413133)

Comment: Yes, you will still need to decide how you want to handle `ZoneId`s that translate to the same display name in your langauge. I am thinking one option is to add the ID after each, for example “Central European Time - Europe/Rome” and “Central European Time - Europe/Oslo”. Not the most beautiful solution, but I think it should be navigable for the user.

Comment: @OleV.V. this is an option but you have the difference in language then. So if your user is German then an item like "Zentraleuropäische Zeit - Europe/Rome" would be shown, mixing German and the English zone ID.

Comment: I stick to that solution because there is none better for now. However, there is one difference with my implementation. I included the zone offset before making the list distinct to support zone IDs with same display name but different offset.

Comment: I've found the locale support to be limited. For instance: `ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo").getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.forLanguageTag("jp"))` produces "Japan Time"