# Get all timezones in Dutch

Tags: java, localization, timezone

I would like to get a list of all timezones in Dutch.
My first attempt was ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds(). This however returned a list in English.

Using the answer as provided here: [Localized name of ZoneId's ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070956/localized-name-of-zoneids-id) provided me with a list of timezones in Dutch, but not all are translated, the translation isn't great, and I can't even find the Dutch/Amsterdam time zone in there.

Is there any other way to do this? Maybe a different library I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open-source code you can find [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/timezone).
Unfortunately, they haven't pushed this to Maven Central so that you could import that in your `pom.xml`
You can

1. Try to push it to maven central (quite automated processes).
2. `git clone` that source and maven build/package such that your `.m2` repo will contain that in your local `.m2` repo.
   And then use that in your real project, like importing it into your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Looking at that library it uses an online service right? That is not great for me since this is a project that might have to run without internet.

Comment: if you build the whole project in your local, it will be stored in you `.m2` repo, thus no need for internet.