# JavaFX Linechart with Time

Tags: java, csv, javafx

I am programming a little Tool which can read in csv Files and show their Data in a Line Chart. My current Problem is that i don't know how to make Axis with Time, which easily can use the Data of the CSV File.

Thats the format of the Date and Time in the csv File

```
    Date;Time
    06.08.2015;00:00:00;
```

My first try was to convert it in to a LocalDateTime variable. But the Line Chart is not able to sort it.

Comment: Try separating with commas. CSV stands for Comma-Separated Values

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529956/sorting-x-axis-in-chart-by-the-dates-javafx/34532538#34532538 helps.