# How to combine date and time into a single object?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

my dao page is receiving date and time from two different field  now i want know how to merge these both date and time in a single object so that i calculate time difference and total time. I have this code to merge but it is not working what am i doing wrong in this code please help.

```
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-01-02");
    Date t = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse("04:05:06");
    LocalDate datePart = new LocalDate(d);
    LocalTime timePart = new LocalTime(t);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = datePart.toLocalDateTime(timePart);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8?rq=1

Comment: Your `t` isn't actually a time. It's a date. 1st January 1970 at 4:05 am.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: that doesn’t stop you from treating it like a time and extract the time part, e.g. `t.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()`. You have to deal with this pattern, e.g. when you encounter a [`java.sql.Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/sql/Time.html) instance…

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You just need to use the correct methods, instead of calling constructors. Use `parse` to create local date and local time objects, then pass the two objects to the `of` method of `LocalDateTime`:

```
    LocalDate datePart = LocalDate.parse("2013-01-02");
    LocalTime timePart = LocalTime.parse("04:05:06");
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(datePart, timePart);
```

EDIT

Apparently, you need to combine two `Date` objects instead of 2 strings. I guess you can first convert the two dates to strings using `SimpleDateFormat`. Then use the methods shown above.

```
String startingDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(startDate);
String startingTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(startTime);
```

Comment: Perfect demonstration of the simplicity of the new DateTime API. I might suggest pointing out why the above it's working - i.e. that `t` is actually a date and there is no support for "time" pre Java 8.

Comment: its throwing error incompatible type string cannot converted to LocalDate

Comment: Are you sure you are using methods like `parse` and `of` and not directly assigning a string to `datePart`? @deepakrawat

Comment: String startingDate = this.startDate;                                                      String startingTime = this.startTime;                                           LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(startingDate, startingTime);

Comment: i am hoding date and time in a string then merge it in a object.

Comment: @deepak rawat: the beginning of this answer shows how to convert a `String` into a `LocalDate` resp. `LocalTime`.

Comment: Its important to note that this require api 26 and higher

Comment: It's require API 26 and higher, so what about 21+?

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko You _can_ use this without requiring API 26 if you use Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0. [There is now desugaring support.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) Otherwise, [there is also a backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 5):

To combine date and time in java 8 you can use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.
This also allows you to format with `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Example program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2013, 1, 2);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(4, 5, 6);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm a");
        System.out.println(localDateTime.format(format));
    }
```

Comment: I got a warning here. Call requires API level 26 (current min is 15): java.time.LocalDate#of

Answer (score 3):

Simple yet effective would be:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(datePart, timePart);
```