# Addition of two dates

Tags: java, android

I have two dates of type `String`, the first in the format `"yyyy.MM.dd"`, the second `"HH: mm"`

They converted them to a `Date` type using `SimpleDateFormat`;

So, I need to put them together, that is, the result should be `"yyyy.MM.dd HH: mm"` Are there other options for how to add them, except

```
date.setHours();
date.setMinutes();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are deprecated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752557/how-to-combine-date-and-time-into-a-single-object

Comment: If one is a date and the other is time, why not concat the two strings and then parse the result once?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, Thank you. I did not think about it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "java.time.LocalDateTime". This also allows you to format with java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.

Example program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2013, 1, 2);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(4, 5, 6);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm a");
        System.out.println(localDateTime.format(format));
    }
```