# How to get current timestamp in Scala as a string without spaces?

Tags: scala

I want to get for example a string of the current time: "20180122_101043". How can I do this?

I can create a `val cal = Calendar.getInstance()` but I'm not sure what to do with it after.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Calendar` is not the best choice here. Use:

- `java.util.Date` + `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` if you have java 7 or below

  `new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date)`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime` + `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` for java 8+ 
  `LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd_HHmmss"))`

Comment: @osk added examples

Comment: Thank you! Very simple, I was trying to extract each component by itself (year, month and so on)

Answer (score 34):

`LocalDateTime` is what you might want to use,

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDateTime

scala> LocalDateTime.now()
res60: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-01-22T01:21:03.048
```

If you don't want default `LocalDateTime` format which is basically [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) without zone info, you can apply `DateTimeFormatter` as below,

```
scala> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

scala> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm").format(LocalDateTime.now)
res61: String = 2018-01-22_01:21
```

**Related resource** - [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22463063/432903)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of Java 8 Date/Time API:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val format = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"

val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)

val ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 22, 10, 10, 43) // 20180122_101043

ldt.format(dtf)
```

To get the current time, use `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `java.time` library. For instance:

```
import java.time
val s: String = time.LocalDateTime.now().toString
println(s)
```

gives `2021-04-23T14:13:01.163869`. Then you need to manipulate the string, e.g.

```
time.LocalDateTime.now().toString.replace("T","_").replace("-","").replace(":","")
```

for `20210423_141639.769222`.