# Add timestamp column to RDD using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD with thousands of entries as (Int, Double) which I would like to add a column as a timestamp, such that it becomes (Int, Double, Datetime). I tried the following:

```
    val addTimeStampRDD = OriginalRDD.map {
      case(a, b) =>
        (a, b, current_timestamp())}
```

Unfortunately the job to fail with errors such as:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
```

Is this because the timestamp is a SQL function? Is there a better alternative than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the result in Spark you can use `LocalDateTime` from `java.time.LocalDateTime`

You can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378006/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-scala-as-a-string-without-spaces)

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDateTime

scala> LocalDateTime.now()
```

You can also use `DateTimeFormatter` to format the date in required format

```
scala> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

scala> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm").format(LocalDateTime.now)
```