# Java date pattern seperated by hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I want to know if this is the right pattern for matches string like following

String samples

```
23.04.2019-30.04.2019
3.06.2019-20.06.2019
```

Pattern

```
private final Pattern TIMELINE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4}-\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4}$");
```

Comment: There are already date utilities for this

Comment: Apparently not. The second sample doesn't start with two numbers. Also you probably want to escape `.`, otherwise it matches any character. There may be other issues, but these are the most obvious.

Comment: @Reimeus Could you please point me to some. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the day/month components could be one *or* two digit characters, then you should use this pattern:

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$
```

### Demo

Presumably the years might also not be fixed width, but it is probably unlikely that a year earlier than 1000 would appear, so we can fix the year at 4 digits.  Also, literal dot in a regex pattern needs to be escaped with a backslash.

**Edit:**

If you want to first validate the string, and then separate the two dates, then consider this:

```
String input = "3.06.2019-20.06.2019";
if (input.matches("\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{4}")) {
    String[] dates = input.split("-");
    System.out.println("date1: " + dates[0]);
    System.out.println("date2: " + dates[1]);
}
```

Comment: Sir is there also a way we can extract those two dates seperated by hyphen within the same operation

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Check my updated answer.  You may use `String#split` to extract the two dates, after you validate using your current regex.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Perfect !

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in your current regex,

- First quantifier needs to be `{1,2}` instead of just `{2}` to support either one digit or two
- You need to escape dot

The correct regex you need to use should be this,

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}-\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGZQfX/1)**

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("23.04.2019-30.04.2019", "3.06.2019-20.06.2019");

list.forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.matches("^\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}-\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}$"));
});
```

Prints,

```
23.04.2019-30.04.2019 --> true
3.06.2019-20.06.2019 --> true
```

Comment: Presumably the day could be 1/2 digits in _either_ of the two dates.  And also, `String#matches` implicitly puts anchors around the pattern, so using `^` and `$` in your code is redundant.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: My regex was for the data he has given. But yes if other fields can have one or two digits, then we can use `{1,2}` there as well.