# How to parse/convert a string column in dataframe to datetime column with Scala

Tags: scala, datetime-format

My current data is in this format: `2013-07-25 00:00:00.0`,

`orders.take(10).foreach(println)`

```
1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED
2,2012-07-25 00:00:00.0,256,PENDING_PAYMENT
3,2011-07-25 00:00:00.0,12111,COMPLETE
4,2014-07-25 00:00:00.0,8827,CLOSED
5,2015-07-25 00:00:00.0,11318,COMPLETE
6,2016-07-25 00:00:00.0,7130,COMPLETE
7,2017-07-25 00:00:00.0,4530,COMPLETE
8,2018-07-25 00:00:00.0,2911,PROCESSING
9,2019-07-25 00:00:00.0,5657,PENDING_PAYMENT
10,2009-07-25 00:00:00.0,5648,PENDING_PAYMENT
```

I know how to convert the string to int:

```
val ordersMap = orders.map(a=>(
a.split(",")(0).toInt, 
a.split(",")(1), 
a.split(",")(2).toInt, 
a.split(",")(3)
))
```

But, for the second column date in string format, I am looking for a easy way like `.toInt`, all I want is to parse it into a datetime.

I wonder if there is a simple way to do that on all the rows in the dataframe, and if there is a flexible way to accommodate different datetime formats, like `yyyy/mm/dd`, `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, etc.

Thank you.

**[UPDATE1]**
Thanks to @smac89's suggestion, I tried with no luck, screenshot is here:

[image]

Comment: Try [How to Convert String to LocalDateTime in Java 8 - Example Tutorial](https://www.java67.com/2016/04/how-to-convert-string-to-localdatetime-in-java8-example.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

Comment: Are you using `apache-spark`? If so, you can load directly as `Timestamp` datatype.

Comment: Thank you Cesar, can you write up an answer with screenshot please? I am using Databricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended with, cumbersome but working:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

......

```
val datetime_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val test="2013-07-25 00:00:..."
val myd = test.substring(0,10).format(datetime_format)
val mydate = datetime_format.parse(myd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `LocalDate.parse` as in the duplicate, but AFAIK there is no such extension for dates. You can easily create your own though:

```scala
implicit class StringDates(ds: String) {
    def toLocalDate: LocalDate = ds.toLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    def toLocalDate(fmt: DateTimeFormatter): LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(ds, fmt)
}
```

Now you can do:

```
"2013-07-25".toLocalDate
```

Or pass in a formatter by doing:

```
"2013-07-25".toLocalDate(fmt)
```

[Try it on Scastie 1](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/24XPtJGzRjeYQFVNvjbLkw)
[Try it on Scastie 2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/weIJqjJAS5CQAnnoSTah9Q)

You can create more formatters easily by doing:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/mm/dd")
```

See [Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Comment: @mdivk that was my mistake. For some reason, I thought we were talking about `kotlin` and didn't see the `scala` tag. I will change my answer

Comment: Thank you @smac89, would it be possible for you to share a bit more details? like is there any libraries to import? Can you cut a screenshot of your notebook?

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out later and update here

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion in your edit, that's for Java, not Scala