# What is the correct way to format a date string to m/d/yyyy from "2020-05-08T11:01:48.3300000Z" datetime string in java/ Kotlin

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin, utc

I am trying to format a DateTime string that is received from the server. I have used the below formats and none is working - AppConstants.API_DATE_TIME_FORMAT =

```
 - `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`
 - `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'Z'"`
 - `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`
 - `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX'Z'"`
 - `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'"`

 and - 

     fun getFormattedDate(apiFormatDateTime: String): String {
        return try{
            val parser = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.API_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.UI_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            val date = parser.parse(apiFormatDateTime)!!
            formatter.format(date)
        }catch (ex : Exception){
            apiFormatDateTime
        }
    }
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'` works. But that depends on what `3300000Z` mean. doubtful that you are specifying that big millisecond value.

Comment: if the input is correctly specified as `2020-05-08T11:01:48.330+0000Z` then the format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also *no way exists* that `SimpleDateFormat` can parse 7 decimals on the seconds correctly. And don’t enclose `Z` in single quotes, it gives you incorrect results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
        String d="2020-05-08T11:01:48.3300000Z";
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date date = originalFormat.parse(d);
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
        System.out.println("date==>"+formattedDate);
```

Output::

```
date==>20200508
```

Comment: @Trishuul it gives me 1/8/2020

Comment: @BajrangHudda That is just not possible. Your output has / whereas I have not used / anywhere in my code. If you want / in your output replace the line `DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Comment: UI_DATE_FORMAT = "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: @BajrangHudda the format should be `MM/dd/yyyy` notice the uppercase and lowercase letters. 2 M for months, 2 d for date, 4 y for year. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, And how i can get time from this in this formate - "07:54:56 am"

Comment: Try this `DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");`

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary Using your suggested `DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");`. Expected: `date==>05/08/2020 11:01:48 AM` (or similar in user’s time zone). Observed: `05/08/2020 11:56:48 AM`. It’s 55 minutes off. It’s not you. It’s `SimpleDateFormat` misbehaving yet again. I recommend that no one uses that class.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. In Java (because this is what I can write):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    DateTimeFormatter uiDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");

    String isoF8601ormatDateTime = "2020-05-08T11:01:48.3300000Z";
    Instant time = Instant.parse(isoF8601ormatDateTime);
    String uiString = time.atZone(zone)
            .format(uiDateFormatter);

    System.out.println(uiString);
```

Output is:

> 5/8/2020

Points to note:

- The format from your API is ISO 8601. The classes of java.time parse the most common ISO 8601 variants as their default, that is, we need not specify any formatter.
- My code also converts the date to the user’s time zone before formatting. Most users will expect this. Please put your user’s time zone where I put Asia/Kolkata.

Bonus info: to format the time, in the user’s time zone too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter uiTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String uiTimeString = time.atZone(zone).format(uiTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(uiTimeString);
```

> 04:31:48 PM

### What went wrong in your attemtps?

- There exists no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can parse 7 decimals on the seconds correctly. It only supports milliseconds, exactly three decimals. `SimpleDateFormat` takes 3300000 to be milliseconds, that is 3300 seconds or nearly an hour, which it adds to the time parsed.
- `Z` in your incoming string is a UTC offset (of zero) and needs to be parsed as such, or you will get an incorrect result.
- `Z` without quotes will parse an offset like `+0000`, but not `Z`. `XX` will parse `Z`, but that attempt failed because you additionally required (one more) `Z` after the `Z`.
- You did not convert to the user’s time zone before formatting.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1986, Month.APRIL, 8, 12, 30);
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "1986-04-08 12:30"
```

credit to :https://stackoverflow.com/a/22463063/9297896

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like below

```
try {
            XMLGregorianCalendar dt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2020-05-13T12:12:12.123456Z");
            String dateValue = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dt.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
            System.out.println("datevalue="+dateValue);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output: datevalue=05/13/2020

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it for getting date and time from UTC format -

```
    const val API_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"
    const val UI_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    const val UI_TIME_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss a"

/**
     * Function for getting date from api datetime string
     * @return formatted time
     */
    fun getFormattedDate(apiFormatDateTime: String): String {
        return try{
            val parser = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.API_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            parser.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.UI_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            val date = parser.parse(apiFormatDateTime)!!
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
            formatter.format(date)
        }catch (ex : Exception){
            apiFormatDateTime
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function for getting time from api datetime string
     * @return formatted time
     */
    fun getFormattedTime(apiFormatDateTime: String): String {
        return try{
            val parser = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.API_DATE_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            parser.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(AppConstants.UI_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
            formatter.format(parser.parse(apiFormatDateTime)!!)
        }catch (ex : Exception){
            apiFormatDateTime
        }
    }
```