# json remove unneserry timestamp with milliseconds and seconds

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am developing service that returning json only needs to show date time and minutes, but it shows everything on time stamp. How to get rid of milliseconds and seconds ?

My model below;

```
private LocalDateTime processStartDate;
```

My RowMapper bewlow;

```
taskList.setProcessStartDate(rs.getTimeStamp("PROCESS_START_DATE").toLocalDateTime());
```

My Response

```
private LocalDateTime processStartDate;
```

My Json Response Using Postman below;

```
"taskResponseList": [
 {
   "processStartDate" : "2020-02-14T17:30:23.00Z"
 }
]
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8

Comment: I have already saw that, not working

Comment: Add the code where you try using it to the question

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the milliseconds by using the following line of code.

```
taskList.setProcessStartDate(rs.getTimeStamp("PROCESS_START_DATE").toLocalDateTime()).withNano(0);
```

To remove both seconds and milliseconds from the time, you can just use the chorounit to truncate the date:

```
taskList.setProcessStartDate(rs.getTimeStamp("PROCESS_START_DATE").toLocalDateTime()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Edited:

Convert it into into the date format by using **new Date()**

```
 Date date=new Date(rs.getTimeStamp("PROCESS_START_DATE").toLocalDateTime()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES); 
taskList.setProcessStartDate(date)
```

And then use any method to remove the seconds and miliseconds from date

Comment: Hello, still same

Comment: I have used this approached before, unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Hey, I guess you are getting the string type value from the rs. So try to convert it from string to date first

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it on mapper

Comment: yes thank you. But can you please write on mapper how to do it ?

Comment: I  have no idea where to write on mapper. Can you combine your solution with my mapper

Comment: date(long) can not applied localDateTime

Comment: You can just remove localDateTime for instance and check if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also format the way JSON is returned by adding the following to your Response Object :

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime processStartDate;
```