# How to read string timestamp into Java date of form Fri Jul 17 12:41:20 IST 2020?

Tags: java

I have a string in the form of Fri Jul 17 12:41:20 IST 2020 and I want to persist this in MS SQL server table with column type DATETIME.

For that, I first need to convert the above string into Date POJO.

Comment: Try to use `DateTimeFormatter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also store long if needed but there is a basic conversion on string to **Date** or **Long**.

```
 //Fri Jul 17 12:41:20 IST 2020
public static Long getDateTime(String input){
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    try {
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(input);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(DateConverter.getDateTime("Fri Jul 17 12:41:20 IST 2020"));
}
```