# What is pattern for 2000-11-10T00:00:00+02:00

Tags: java, datetime-format

I need to convert string in **2000-11-10T00:00:00+02:00** format to LocalDateTime object. But when I parse this string to LocalDateTime, it gives error.

Which pattern should I use to parse the string to LocalDateTime object?

Comment: What is the error? What pattern are you using now?

Comment: The error is : Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String \"2000-11-10T00:00:00+02:00\". I don't use pattern for now

Comment: What do you mean exactly by “deserialize”? What are you using? Jackson in spring boot?

Comment: Yes I mean jackson

Comment: I notice that it pretty clearly has a time zone on it.

Comment: According to https://www.javatpoint.com/java-localdatetime,
the default format is  yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss.zzz

Comment: Okay, how can I convert time that includes time-zone to LocalDateTime object ?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime`) can parse that format (ISO-8601) directly - no formatter required - and they have methods to convert to a `LocalDateTime`

Comment: I reopened this Question because the [alleged original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22463062/642706) is about parsing a string with only a date and time as a `LocalDateTime`. This Question, in contrast, is about a date, a time, *and* an offset from UTC. The `LocalDateTime` solutions on that Question cannot be applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string contains time zone and `LocalDateTime` does not contgain this information. You need to use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class or [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. The information on the masks is provided [in Javadoc for DateTimeFormatter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2000-11-10T00:00:00+02:00" ) ;
```

Comment: I suggest you drop the “or ZonedDateTime”. The appropriate class here is indeed `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the edit. OffsetDateTime is more appropriate but IMHO ZonedDateTime is still relevant.

Comment: Why would you mention `ZonedDateTime`? There is no time zone involved in your Answer, nor in the Question.

Comment: A `ZonedDateTime` has information like `[Europe/Paris]`. I don't see that in the OPs question.