# How to convert LocalDateTime to human readable string in OQL

Tags: java, heap-dump, oql, eclipse-mat

I am trying to create an **OQL query** in Eclipse MAT to select a bunch of objects from a Java heapdump with `LocalDateTime` fields. Simply calling the `.toString()` function of the object just returns the object address, e.g. this:

```
SELECT mci.firstName.toString(), mci.importantDateTime.toString() AS mydatetime FROM com.example.MyClass$Inner mci WHERE (mci.firstName.toString() = "John")
```

returns `John | java.time.LocalDateTime @ 0x83be8420`

How do I convert the object to a human-readable datetime string?

Once again to make it crystal clear: I don't want to parse a date time in Java. I need an Object Query Language (**OQL**) statement that produces a human readable string out of a `LocalDateTime` field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-can-i-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider No, I need to format it in OQL

Comment: Perhaps just `SELECT mci.firstName, mci.importantDateTime …`?

Comment: @BasilBourque Unfortunately, no, it's not that easy. It just prints the same address in a slightly different format: `java.time.LocalDateTime [id=0x83be8420]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help:

```
SELECT ((((((((((((toString(l.date.year) + "-") + l.date.month) + "-") + l.date.day) + "T") + l.time.hour) + ":") + l.time.minute) + ":") + l.time.second) + ".") + l.time.nano) AS "Local date time" FROM java.time.LocalDateTime l
```

Modify this replacing `l` with `mci.importantDateTime`.

Alternatively, you could write an extension for MAT with a class specific name resolver [org_eclipse_mat_api_nameResolver](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fdoc%2Forg_eclipse_mat_api_nameResolver.html) for `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalTime`.