# How to create a valid DateTime object from String

Tags: android, jodatime

I have the following String.

```
21-Mar-2014
```

How can i convert this into a valid Joda DateTime object?

I've tried the following with no joy:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM/Y");
            DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
```

Thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: try this pattern: dd-MMM-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A genuine joda answer with corrected pattern string and explicit `Locale`:

```
String input = "21-Mar-2014";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(input); // using the default time zone
System.out.println(dt); // 2014-03-21T00:00:00.000+01:00 (my zone: Europe/Berlin)
```

If you don't need time part (regarding your input!) then I recommend to use:

```
LocalDate date = dtf.parseLocalDate(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already so many question in SO related to this.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";
try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Date date1;
String myFormatString = "MMM-dd-yyyy"; // for example
String Your_Date=txtDate.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
date1 = df.parse(Your_Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use the following simple date format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy");
Date date1=sdf.parse("21-Mar-2014");
```

Try this

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
                DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

Comment: OP asks for joda solution else your answer is okay.

Comment: try above edited answer and tell me which version of joda you currently use