# Convert Javascript new Date to Java joda DateTime format

Tags: java, javascript, json, datetime, jodatime

I have an entity at my java backend which has a `joda DateTime` field called createdAt. 
I have a post API to update these values on the Database.
The post API accepts `application/json values`.

I have an use case where in i need to make a Ajax POST request from my javascript file that updates the entity with the current date.

Now that i need to pass a DateTime value in the POST data, i face a problem in converting the `javascript Date object` into `joda DateTime`.

I have tried sending the javascript Date object but it responds as :

Also Note: I cannot perform any actions on the data i receive from javascript before sending it to the repository on the java side.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late perhaps, but:

I had a similar problem. We use `org.joda.time.LocalDate` in our backend and passing a `new Date()` from javascript to the backend resulted in a conversion error.
We solved this by using `new Date().valueOf()` instead. This will get the milliseconds since 1 jan 1970 (read about it at [MDNs JavaScript Date page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)).

After that you could just do `org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(passedInValue)`

Comment: Thanks i got the same problem, your answer saved me today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Objects cannot be "sent" in API calls. Objects are serialized(convert to string in this case) and deserialized(convert to appropriate object from string)

In this case:
 - **Serialization**: Convert the Javascript Date object to appropriate format in a string before making the POST call
 - **Deserialize**: Refer [Converting a date string to a DateTime object using Joda Time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library) to convert the string into a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JavaScript `new Date().toString()`,and post the string value to the server, then you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert this value to any date format in java server.