# Java- milliseconds (SSS) not being parsed with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, simpledateformat

Basically I'm attempting to parse date/time to Java, but having issues when trying to parse the milliseconds.

Example of data to be parsed: **a[0]** = 16/03/2015, **a[1]** = 10:00:18.120

I read in the two values and concatenate them.
Getting: dateTime = (java.lang.String) "16/03/2015 10:00:18.120"
As you can see the string has the milliseconds when i debug it. From here I parse it to SimpleDateFormat. It works- however the milliseconds are not displayed

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateTime;
dateTime= a[0]+" "+a[1];
Date d = df.parse(dateTime);
```

Current output: d = (java.util.Date) Mon Mar 16 10:00:18 GMT 2015

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not exactly a fix to your problem, but you could try parsing into Joda Time instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library

Comment: The `toString()` method of java.util.Date does not output milliseconds. This does not necessarily means that it does not contain them. Use the same SimpleDateFormat to format/convert to String it and you will see...

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try printing it with `System.out.println(df.format(d));`.

Comment: How to format to string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java

Comment: Thanks guys- I was printing it out wrong. Much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but not your interpretation of the result. As correctly mentioned in one comment, the method `toString()` of class `java.util.Date` does not output the millisecond part. But the millisecond part is still part of the state of your result object. Proof:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateTime = "16/03/2015 10:00:18.120";
Date d = df.parse(dateTime);
System.out.println(d); // Mon Mar 16 10:00:18 CET 2015
System.out.println(d.getTime()); // 1426496418120
System.out.println("millisecond-part=" + (d.getTime() % 1000)); // millisecond-part=120
```

So all is fine. You can even format your result back to a string using the same (or another instance of `SimpleDateFormat` - maybe with different pattern, locale and timezone).

If `java.util.Date` was correctly implemented as value-type then the inventors of that class would have taken care of making the output of `toString()` representing the whole exact state of the object but it has not happened - another example why this class is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateFormat.format(Date date)` function might meet your requirement

```
 Date date = new Date();
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS",Locale.ENGLISH);
 String dateTime;
 dateTime=df.format(date);
 String[] a=dateTime.split(" ");
 System.out.println(a[0]+" "+a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS",Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateTime;
    dateTime= "03/16/2015"+" "+"10:00:18.120";
    Date d = df.parse(dateTime);
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String[] a = new String[]{"16/03/2015", "10:00:18.120"};

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateTime = a[0] + " " + a[1];

    try {
        Date d = df.parse(dateTime);
        System.out.println(d.getTime());//Returns milliseconds
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The result: 1426492818120