# How to convert string to datetime of specified format in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a string `10-MAR-1998 14:47` which I need to convert to DateTime object of a specified format. For example: (dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm GMT) in java.

Comment: Your question is unclear - when you say "DateTime object", do you mean a joda DateTime? If not what class are you referring to? Also a date/time object generally represents a point in time but doesn't have a format - you format it when you need to show it to a user using a formatter.

Comment: There might be about thousands of java date format questions out there in SO. I cannot imagine, you didn't find anything.

Comment: check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter
```

and

```
SimpleDateFormat
```

are your friends, my friend.
The only question is, is the date time of the input string also in GMT?

If it is, then:

```
String myString = "10-MAR-1998 14:47";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y H:m");
Date date = format.parse(myString);
```

should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

In your case you would have

```
String str = "10-MAR-1998 14:47";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm");
Date date = df.parse(str);
```

You can also go back from date to string with the specified format like this :

```
String dateStr = df.format(df.parse(date));
```

I know that the library [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

handles quite well date conversion. But you would have to add a dependency to your project and if it's the only thing you need for date conversion right now I would suggest sticking with SimpleDateFormat.