# Not able to convert string dd/MM/yyyy to Date dd/MM/yyyy in java

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I have an input string of the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, I need to convert it into date `dd/MM/yyyy`.

My approach is:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = formatter.format(formatter.parse("22/09/2016"));
Date convertedDate = formatter.parse(date);
```

I was expecting `22/09/2016` as a date object, however the format returned was  not as expected. `O/P=>Mon Sep 12 00:00:00 IST 2016`

Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6252782/5292801)

Comment: You should better describe what's wrong, from your point of view. Because `formatter.parse("22/09/2016")` does already what you want `I was expecting 22/09/2016 as a date object`.

Comment: @Takarii  I'm not using joda library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "22/09/2016" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) )
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) )
```

## Problems

- You are conflating date-time objects with strings representing date-time values. A date-time object can parse a string, and can generate a string, but the date-time object is always separate and distinct from the string. **The string has a format; the date-time object does *not*.**
- You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.
- You are trying to fit a date-only value into a date-time object (square peg, round hole).
- You are being tricked by the poorly-designed `toString` method that silently applies a time zone to an internal value that has no time zone (is UTC).

Be sure to read [the correct Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639811/642706).

## java.time

Using the new java.time classes, specifically `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "22/09/2016" , f );
```

Generate a String to represent that value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString(); // 2016-09-22
```

Generate a String in your desired format by applying the formatter.

```
String output = ld.format( f );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be assuming that a `java.util.Date` "knows" a format. It doesn't. That's not part of its state - it's *just* the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. (There's no time zone either - the IST you're seeing there is your local time zone; that's just part of what `Date.toString()` does.)

Basically, a `Date` is just an instant in time - when you want a particular formatted value, that's when you use `SimpleDateFormat`.

(Or better, use `java.time.*`...)

Think of it like a number - the number sixteen is the same number whether you represent it in binary as 10000, decimal as 16, or hex as 0x10. An `int` value doesn't have any concept of "I'm a binary integer" or "I'm a hex integer" - it's only when you convert it to a string that you need to care about formatting. The exact same thing is true for date/time types.

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date d = formatter.parse("22/09/2016");
            System.out.println(d.toString());
            String e = formatter.format(d);
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Json.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: it is still returning a string, isn't it? I need a date object.

Comment: @robot_alien yes,  you can use 'd'  object.  Its of date type

Answer (score 1):

A `Date`, when printed will call the `toString` method of the object. It will then choose whatever format it wants.

Try

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(convertedDate));
```

or - obviously

```
System.out.println(date);
```