# What DateTime format is this "2017-02-08T18:39:00Z"?

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

I need to deserialize/serialized this date to `Joda` `DateTime` with jackson. Is this a specific `DateTime` format?

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date time format.  JodaTime should be perfectly capable of handling this particular date format [through the use of `DateTimeFormat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6252782/1079354).