# How to transfer this kind of DateFormat "2020-05-29T11:40:55Z" to Date

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to transfer this "2020-05-29T11:40:55Z" to `Date` or `Calender`, if i transfer it directly, like `Date("2020-05-29T11:40:55Z")`, An error would be throw out. Anyone has ideas? 
What's more, My min `Android Api` is 19, So plenty of api for Java 8 and Api26 is prohibited.

Comment: please use **joda time API**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library) question will help.

Comment: first convert it to some other standard format and transfer ...

Comment: @Mandy8055 Joda-Time has been obsolete for several years.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it's not obsolete. It is migrated on java 1.8 `time package`. Please read citations [**here.**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and if something is obsolete i.e. `java.util.Date`

Comment: If you can, avoid `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use `OffsetDateTime` from the `java.time` package instead. It would then be as simple as `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-05-29T11:40:55Z")`.

Comment: If you are targeting Android API levels lower that 26, you could use the ThreeTen Android Backport. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @MCEmperor  yes, my min Api is 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite understand the last part of your question. Are you saying that you cannot use java 8 in your project ? .For java 8 based , use `ZonedDateTime` like :

```
//1 - default pattern
String timeStamp = "2019-03-27T10:15:30";
ZonedDateTime localTimeObj = ZonedDateTime.parse(time);

//2 - specified pattern
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z");
String timeStamp1 = "2019-03-27 10:15:30 AM";
ZonedDateTime localTimeObj1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStamp1, formatter);

//To get LocalDate from ZonedDateTime
LocalDate localDate = localTimeObj1.toLocalDate();
```

Using the old way to get the date :

```
    String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);

    String sDateInAmerica = formatter.format("2019-03-27 10:15:30 AM"); 
    //Create another simpledateformatter with your required format and use it to convert
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat(REQUIRED_DATE_FORMAT);
    Date date = formatter2.parse(sDateInAmerica);
```

Comment: No, I am useing ```Kotlin``` to develop my android project. And A lot of java 8 Api is not supported by low Android Sdk version

Comment: @Cyrus On in that case , you will have to follow the old approach using old api.

Comment: Yes, Are there any way to use old api to transfer it?

Comment: @CyrusI am not good with kotlin but I have updated code with java.