# Extract Date from Zulu Time using Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a Zulu time "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z". How can i extract date part using java joda time?
I have read multiple question on Zulu Time but none answer my question.

Comment: Did you check [Converting a date string to a DateTime object using Joda Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library) ?

Comment: For Java 8 and later use the new built in api

Comment: Which new API ?

Comment: [This API: java.time (Oracle tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). It’s 6 and a half years old and considered the modern Java date and time API and the successor of Joda-Time. Even though it isn’t brand new, to me it still feels that way, in a very good way. I warmly recommend it.

Comment: Do you want the date in your time zone or the date in UTC (Zulu)?

Comment: @pritisharma - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the date in your own time zone or in Zulu (UTC)? Asking because it is never the same date in all time zones.

**Date in Zulu time zone**, the same date as in the string, is the easier requirement:

```
    String zuluString = "2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(zuluString);
    LocalDate datePart = dt.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(datePart);
```

Output:

> 2011-08-12

Getting the date **in the default time zone of the JVM** just requires a few chars more:

```
    LocalDate datePart = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Output when run in Asia/Macau time zone:

> 2011-08-13

### Which new API ?

Joda-Time is in maintenance mode and no longer recommended for new code. The Joda-Time home page says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
> No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
> to `java.time` (JSR-310).

java.time is built into Java since Java 8 and has also been backported to Java 6 and 7. You may start by following the second link below.

### Links

- [Joda-Time - Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Using the modern `java.time (JSR-310)` API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z");
        System.out.println(odt);

        LocalDate date = odt.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
2011-08-12
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Check out the following lines from the [home page of Joda-Time documentation](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html):

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Using the Joda-Time API:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z");
        System.out.println(dateTime);

        LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z
2011-08-12
```